# Merge Multiple txt files and removing duplicates from resulting big file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been trying to get this one to work, without success because:

The files to be merged are large (up to 20MB each);
Duplicate lines come in separate files. That's why I need to remove it from the resulting merged file;

Right now, the code is running, but nothing shows up and it basically merged the files, not dealing with duplicates.

```
import os
import io
import pandas as pd


merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\txt"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\txt", file)
        bytes = open(file_path, 'rb').read()
        merged_df = merged_df.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
            bytes.decode('latin-1')), sep=";", parse_dates=['Data']))
        SellOutCombined = open('test.txt', 'a')
        SellOutCombined.write(merged_df.to_string())
        SellOutCombined.close()


print(len(merged_df))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just out of couriosity: why are you reading the file into memory? doesn't reading it using `read_csv` with keyword `encoding` work for you?

Comment: As an enthusiast, I wouldn't know how to implement it in different ways. I'll look into how this works out, but at first, I'm trying to get it to do the job, which it isn't - yet. :)

Comment: I see. To drop the duplicates, you can try if that helps: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: One other hint: check out the `with` clause. So rather open your files like this: `with open(filename as SellOutCombined:` then in the next line `SellOutCombined.write(...`. You don't need to close the file this way and it will even be closed if there is an exception. Btw. your file, from which you read the content is probably also not closed properly. That might cause problems in some cases.

Comment: With makes sure an object is usable within the following code block and that it is porperly "deconstructed" after the block is exited without bothering you as the programmer to think about doing that yourself.